# How to read a field Oracle containing XML

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xml-parsing, type-conversion

A table exists in the environment of production with the following structure:

```
 CREATE TABLE gold_dwh_reload (
  msisdn              NUMBER(13,0)   NOT NULL,
  recharge_date       TIMESTAMP(6)   NOT NULL,
  impacted_balances   VARCHAR2(4000) NULL,
  lc_state            VARCHAR2(5)    NOT NULL)
  TABLESPACE sopfun_tab
  NOCOMPRESS
/
```

A normal consultation would the following result by example:

```
MSISDN  RECHARGE_DATE   IMPACTED_BALANCES   LC_STATE
584124723950    29.04.15 13:23:38.000   <balance><name>B_LPP_Bs_Main</name><label></label><before>697.21429</before><after>797.21429</after><amount>100</amount><start></start><end></end><unit>Bs</unit></balance><balance><name>B_LPP_KB_National</name><label>PA_Adjustment</label><before>0</before><after>10240</after><amount>10240</amount><start>29042015000000</start><end>29052015000000</end><unit>Kbytes</unit></balance><balance><name>B_LSP_Bs_Promotions</name><label>PA_Adjustment</label><before>0</before><after>25</after><amount>25</amount><start>29042015000000</start><end>29052015000000</end><unit>Bs</unit></balance> ACT
```

But i need to break the IMPACTED_BALANCES field in columns. Anyone know how I do it?

Comment: What, exactly, is the output you want?  Do you want to take one row from the table and produce multiple rows of output?  If so, what do you want that output to look like?  Are you trying to parse out a set number of known attributes?  Or do you want the number of columns in the output to be dynamic based on the contents of the XML?  What happens if different rows in the table have structurally different XML snippets?  Exactly what version of Oracle are you using (XQuery options may differ across versions)?

Comment: what release do you have? 9i? 10g? 11g? 12c ??? check database documentation, search for: XMLType Operations

Comment: @JustinCave I want to get something like this: 584124720289 05.05.15 17:13:52.000 B_LPP_Bs_Main  626.89287 826.89287 200   Bs ACT.

Comment: @Eng.SamerT I have Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically done using [XMLTable](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions268.htm#SQLRF06232)

```
select
    msisdn, recharge_date,
    x_name, x_label, x_before, x_after, x_amount,
    to_date(x_start, 'DDMMYYYYHH24MISS') x_start,
    to_date(x_end, 'DDMMYYYYHH24MISS') x_end,
    x_unit,
    lc_state
from gold_dwh_reload
cross join
xmltable('/balances/balance'
    passing xmltype('<balances>'||impacted_balances||'</balances>')
    columns
        x_name path '/balance/name',
        x_label path '/balance/label',
        x_before number path '/balance/before',
        x_after number path '/balance/after',
        x_amount number path '/balance/amount',
        x_start path '/balance/start',
        x_end path '/balance/end',
        x_unit path '/balance/unit'
);
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/822c4/4).

Mixing SQL and XML is powerful but creates many potential type safety issues.  A single invalid date, number, or XML file will crash the whole query.  The string in your example is not valid XML, that's why I concatenated another tag to the beginning and end.

Comment: How I can solve the Cartesian product of the cross join? @jon

Comment: @alemarchan You don't need to, Oracle creates a lateral join between the two using the `passing` clause.  The rows should line up.